# How to pass in a starting sequence number to a Django factory_boy factory?

Tags: python, django, class-method, factory-boy

factory_boy defaults to `1` for sequences.  How can I pass in a number to use as a different starting number instead?  I can subclass the `_setup_next_sequence()` method, but how can I give it a variable to use?

```
# File: models.py
from django.db import models

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

```
# File: factories.py
from .models import Book
import factory

class BookFactory(factory.Factory):
  FACTORY_FOR = BookModel  
  title = factory.Sequence(lambda n: u'Title #{}'.format(n))

  @classmethod
  def _setup_next_sequence(cls):      
      # Instead of defaulting to starting with number 1, start with starting_seq_num.
      # But how do I set starting_seq_num?
      return starting_seq_num
```

```
# File: make_data.py
from factories import BookFactory

# somehow set starting sequence number here?

BookFactory().create()
```

I'm using factory_boy 1.2.0 (via `pip install factory_boy`)
factory_boy code: https://github.com/dnerdy/factory_boy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found two ways of solving this:

1. Use a module variable
2. Use a class attribute set outside of the class definition

**Use a module variable:**

```python
# File: factories.py
from .models import Book
import factory

starting_seq_num = 0

class BookFactory(factory.Factory):
  FACTORY_FOR = BookModel  
  title = factory.Sequence(lambda n: u'Title #{}'.format(n))

  @classmethod
  def _setup_next_sequence(cls):      
      # Instead of defaulting to starting with 0, start with starting_seq_num.
      return starting_seq_num

# File: make_data.py
import factories

factories.starting_seq_num = 100    
factories.BookFactory().create()
```

**Use a class attribute set outside of the class definition:**

```python
# File: factories.py
from .models import Book
import factory

class BookFactory(factory.Factory):
  # Note that starting_seq_num cannot be set here in the class definition,
  # because Factory will then pass it as a kwarg to the model's create() method
  # and cause an exception.  It must be set outside the class definition.
  FACTORY_FOR = BookModel  
  title = factory.Sequence(lambda n: u'Title #{}'.format(n))

  @classmethod
  def _setup_next_sequence(cls):      
      return getattr(cls, 'starting_seq_num', 0)

# File: make_data.py
from factories import BookFactory

BookFactory.starting_seq_num = 100
BookFactory().create()
```

Answer (score 10):

In addition to the answer of [Rob Bednark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15418343/5456690)

We can use [`reset_sequence()`](http://factoryboy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference.html#factory.Factory.reset_sequence) function, which will **reset** the counter to a **specific value**.

```
# File: make_data.py
import factories

factories.BookFactory.reset_sequence(100)
my_book = factories.BookFactory().create()
print(my_book.title) # Title #100
```

Answer (score 6):

**Update: `factory_boy` now handles it!**

In the latest version of `factory_boy` (`2.8.1` to this day) it is now possible to [force the sequence counter](http://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes.html#forcing-the-sequence-counter) into a define value:

> Forcing the value on a per-call basis
>
> In order to force the counter for a specific `Factory` instantiation, just pass the value in the
>   `__sequence=42` parameter:

```
class AccountFactory(factory.Factory):
        class Meta:
            model = Account
        uid = factory.Sequence(lambda n: n)
        name = "Test"
```

Then in the console:

```
>>> obj1 = AccountFactory(name="John Doe", __sequence=10)
>>> obj1.uid  # Taken from the __sequence counter
10
>>> obj2 = AccountFactory(name="Jane Doe")
>>> obj2.uid  # The base sequence counter hasn't changed
1
```

And it is also possible to reset the counter to a specific value:

```
>>> AccountFactory.reset_sequence(42)
>>> AccountFactory().uid
42
>>> AccountFactory().uid
43
```

Answer (score 1):

The third, and simplest way:

```python
# File: factories.py
from .models import BookModel
import factory

class BookFactory(factory.Factory, starting_seq_num):
  FACTORY_FOR = BookModel  
  title = factory.Sequence(lambda n: u'Title #{}'.format(n + starting_seq_num))

# File: make_data.py
import factories

book = factories.BookFactory(512).create()  #Start with 512
```

I'm only starting with Factory Boy myself, and not too experienced in Python either, so I may be missing something, but you see where I'm going here. To make it clearer, I think I'd actually prefer it to be keyworded:

```
class BookFactory(factory.Factory, title_seq_start=-1):
...
book = factories.BookFactory(title_seq_start=512).create()
```

Comment: this throws error. How are you extending from undefined variable?